# Opposite of "most of"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that I can use to describe the something being less than 50% but not completely void.

For example:

> *(Least)* of the voters were for the unappealing policy change, but there were a few supporters.

I know "least of" is the wrong phrase to use here, but I'm wondering if there's something that could be used in a similar way.

Is there something I can use here?

Comment: "A minority of"?

Comment: You're most likely to hear "some of" (with mass nouns) or "a few of" (with count nouns).

Comment: *Fewest among*?

Comment: @KateBunting "A minority of" is perfect. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.